# How to use a regular expression in querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink, css-selectors, selectors-api

On a page I'm doing I will be ending up with custom `link` elements like this:

```html
<link rel="multiply" type="service/math" src="path/to/service">
<link rel="substract" type="service/math" src="path/to/service">
...
```

I'm trying to use `querySelectorAll` to retrieve all link elements with a type `service/...` specified and am getting nowhere.

Currently I'm selecting this:

```js
root.querySelectorAll('link');
```

which gives me all `<link>` elements when I only want the ones with type `service/.*`

**Questions:**
Can I add a regex to a QSA selector? If so, how to do it?

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38711853/7250868

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can't really use a regular expression in a selector but CSS selectors are powerful enough for your need with a "starts with" syntax inspired by regexes.

You can use a substring matching attribute selectors  : `link[type^=service]`

Reads "Nodes of type `link` with an attribute `type` starting with "service"

From the [formal specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings):

> **[att^=val]**
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.

#### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49YGf/)

Comment: @frequent you're welcome! For what it's worth, a `.filter` call through the elements checking their type property is also a perfectly valid solution imho.

Comment: this is useful for trying to gain access to a controller instance using the Controller-As syntax in Angular JS 1.5+.  This is exactly the answer I needed when updating my angular app using the controller-as syntax and wanted to have console-level access to their scopes: `angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( '[ng-controller^="' + <controller name> + '"' )[0] ).scope`

Answer (score 19):

I know this is 7 years old, but this is how you do it (for attribute values):

```js
function DOMRegex(regex) {
    let output = [];
    for (let i of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
        if (regex.test(i.type)) { // or whatever attribute you want to search
            output.push(i);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
console.log(DOMRegex(/^service\//)); // your regex here
```

```html
<link rel="multiply" type="service/math" src="path/to/service">
<link rel="substract" type="service/math" src="path/to/service">
<link rel="test" type="notservice/math" src="path/to/notservice">
<div id="some-other-node"></div>
```

To search *all* element attributes, you can use this:

```js
function DOMRegex(regex) {
    let output = [];
    for (let i of document.querySelectorAll('*')) {
        for (let j of i.attributes) {
            if (regex.test(j.value)) {
                output.push({
                    'element': i,
                    'attribute name': j.name,
                    'attribute value': j.value
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
console.log(DOMRegex(/(?<!t)service/)); // your regex here
```

```html
<link rel="multiply" type="service/math" src="path/to/service">
<link rel="substract" type="service/math" src="path/to/service">
<link rel="test" type="notservice/math" src="path/to/notservice">
<div id="some-other-node"></div>
```

I put it in a nice object layout for you.

Comment: I liked this so much that I combined both functions into a single parameterized function - [you can find a "gist" of that code here](https://gist.github.com/oze4/990e0846b0b535785b3f34c5df89be5e)

Comment: You can use `const` instead of `let` in for..of loops. And needless to say, querying and iterating every element isn't going to be performant.

Answer (score 5):

The post is quite old but it may be helpful for someone. If `like` clause is needed and we don't want to search by only the start, the following syntax can be used:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[type*=service]');
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example below:

```html
<link rel="multiply" type="service/math" src="path/to/service">
<link rel="substract" type="service/math" src="path/to/service">
```

You cannot use **Regular Expression(Regex)** but can use **CSS Selector** for `querySelectorAll()` as well as `querySelector()` as shown below. *You can see [6.2. Substring matching attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).

`link[type^="service"]` can select all `<link>`s whose `type` attribute starts from `service`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('link[type^="service"]');
// rel="multiply"'s <link> and rel="substract"'s <link>
```

`[type^="service"]` can also select all `<link>`s whose `type` attribute starts from `service` but I don't recommend it without `link` because it is less specific so it may also select other elements:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[type^="service"]');
// rel="multiply"'s <link> and rel="substract"'s <link>
```

`link[type*="service"]` can also select all `<link>`s whose `type` attribute contains `service`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('link[type*="service"]');
// rel="multiply"'s <link> and rel="substract"'s <link>
```

In addition, `link[src&="service"]` can also select all `<link>`s whose `src` attribute ends with `service`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('link[src&="service"]');
// rel="multiply"'s <link> and rel="substract"'s <link>
```