# Seeking a selector for child elements in dom scrape

Tags: javascript, selector

I am unable to change any html on the website in question.

Here is some html:

```
<ul id="utility-menu" class="menu menu--primary">

        <li><a class="" href="https://www.example.com/newsstand" target="_blank">Magazines</a></li>

        <li><a class="" href="https://secure.bla.com/example/promo/GiveAGift/" target="_blank">Gifts</a></li>

        <li>

          <a href="/email_check?lang=fr">Français</a>
        </li>

            <li><a class="" href="/signin">Sign In</a></li>

        <li>
          <div class="i-am-canadian">
            <img alt="Canadian flag" height="23px;" src="https://secure.example.com/assets/images/icons/ui/i-canadian-c8a132ad64588dcc0b2e61cc589dfef3.png" width="40px;">
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I managed to select the menu using:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu--primary')[0]
```

The element I'm interested in is:

```
<a href="/email_check?lang=fr">Français</a>
```

This element i a language selection for the site visitor that will be either "English" or "Français".

If the user is on an English language page the value of the element will be that shown. But if they are on the French language equivalent the element will be `<a href="/email_check?lang=en">English</a>`

I would like a selector that returns either "English" or "Français".

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

```
var el = document.querySelector('#utility-menu a[href^="/email_check?lang="').textContent;
```

It will select first `a` element with attribute `href` begining with `/email_check?lang=` in `#utility-menu`. Probably you can `.trim()` text to get rid of whitespaces.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. What is the hat ^ doing next to the equals sign?

Comment: @DougFirr it matches attribute whose value begins with the given prefix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791527/can-i-use-a-regular-expression-in-queryselectorall

Answer (score 1):

If your html is not going to change much, you can use

```
var test = document.querySelector("ul > li > a[href='/email_check?lang=fr']");

console.log(test.textContent); // Français
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u4vjq8ah/

Comment: `.innerText` isn't standard compliant, you should use `textContent` instead.