# querySelectorAll for dyanmic span id

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to call the below through in Google Tag Manager:

```js
document.getElementById('Travel_J608883332').innerText
```

An issue I have is that the ID changes with each booking i.e. the `J608883332` is dynamic to the booking number.

I have read about using the querySelectorAll method to create a Regex pattern that might pull back the element dynamically:

```js
return document.querySelectorAll('span[id="^TravelBy\_J.*"]').innertext
```

However the above is returning "undefined" when I test in Google Tag Manager. I assume I have made an error in constructing it?

Apologies for the naive question, I am new to this method.

Thanks,
M

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a regular expression in querySelectorAll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791527/can-i-use-a-regular-expression-in-queryselectorall)

Answer (score 2):

You can use with a [prefix attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). In addition, the collection returned by `document.querySelectorAll()` doesn't have an `innerText` attribute. In this example, I've converted the collection to an array, and extract an the texts by mapping the items. If you only have a single element each time, use `document.querySelector()`, and then you can extract the inner text directly.

```js
const text = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span[id^="TravelBy_"]'))
  .map(el => el.innerText);

console.log(text);
```

```html
<span id="TravelBy_123">123</span>
<span id="TravelBy_456">456</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList and innerText is not an attribute of NodeList. 
Other point is querySelectorAll does not support regular expression but you can use CSS selector instead:

```
var queryResult = document.querySelectorAll('span[id^="Travel"]');
console.log(queryResult.innerText); // >>> undefined
console.log(queryResult != null && queryResult.length > 0 ? queryResult[0].innerText : '-');
```