# How to find multiple elements in HTML by comparison to an array of data attributes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firefox-addon, element, queryselector

Given HTML:

```
<div class="element" data-name="cat">
<div class="element" data-name="bird">
<div class="element" data-name="dog">
```

I want to find only the elements that match a data attribute that im keeping in an array like this

`let Array1 = ["dog","cat","lizard"]`

I thought I could do it with querySelectorAll and data attribute filter but its not working at all. Returns an empty nodelist.

`let Elements = document.body.querySelectorAll('.element[data-name="${Array1}"]')`

Im working on a firefox extension looking at a webpage, so I can't touch the HTML and would prefer to stay in pure javascript. Im very new at programming and this is a personal project.

Comment: You can’t put an array in a css selector your gonna have to loop through the array or do some clever reduce trick with multiple selectors

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's [no shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791527/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-in-queryselectorall). I would recommend to loop through your array of possible values. Since [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a `NodeList`, you need to use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) to expand it into your array of captured elements.

```js
const className = 'element',
    attribute = 'data-name',
    attribute_values = ['cat', 'bird', 'dog'],
    elements = [];
for (let value of attribute_values) {
    elements.push(...document.querySelectorAll('.' + className + '[' + attribute + '=' + value + ']'));
}
```

Comment: I see now, I got this to work. Thank you much

Comment: Thank you for the update, @AnnaFLYTE. If this answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer so this question is considered solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

There is no direct way to do that, because the *querySelector* is designed to only select elements based on a single css/attribute selector. However, we can achieve that by repeating the query for multiple times.

**Code**

```
// Method 1: Loop through all the elements with attributes ['data-name']
// Then, apply filter to search for particular attribute value
const elementsWithAttrDataName = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name]');
const results = Array.from(elementsWithAttrDataName).filter(ele => {
  return ele.getAttribute('data-name') === 'cat' || ele.getAttribute('data-name') === 'dog';
});
console.log(results.length);


// Method 2: Loop through all the keys you want to search for
var elements = [];
let keys = ["cat", "dog"];
keys.forEach(function(key){
    elements.push(document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="'+key+'"]'));
});

console.log(elements.length);
```